# integral of $e^{x}f(x)$

Tags: integration

Can someone explain me in detail how this result has been found using integration by parts
$$\int_{-1}^{1} e^{ikr\mu}f(\mu) d\mu = \frac{e^{ikr}f(1) - e^{-ikr}f(-1)}{ikr} + O(\frac{1}{k^2r^2})$$ where $\mu = cos(\theta)$, provided $\frac{df}{d\mu}$ is bounded.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int_{-1}^1 f(\mu) v'(\mu) \, d\mu = [f(\mu) v(\mu)]_{\mu=-1}^1 - \int_{-1}^1 f'(\mu) v(\mu) \, d\mu$$
where $v(\mu) = \frac{e^{ikr\mu}}{ikr}$.

Comment: ooouuu. Sorry for being so dumb and thanks for your reply.:P